# protobuf-net ShouldSerialize* and *Specified are ignored

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Both the ShouldSerialize* and *Specified methods are being ignored when converting an object to protocol buffers.

Given the following request generated with the `-p:detectMissing` flag:

```
message RpbIndexReq {
    enum IndexQueryType {
        eq = 0;
        range = 1;
    }

    required bytes bucket = 1;
    required bytes index = 2;
    required IndexQueryType qtype = 3;
    optional bytes key = 4; // key here means equals value for index?
    optional bytes range_min = 5;
    optional bytes range_max = 6;
    optional bool return_terms = 7;
    optional bool stream = 8;
    optional uint32 max_results = 9;
    optional bytes continuation = 10;
}
```

`max_results` is initialized to 0 and sent across the wire.

The RpbIndexReq is generated like this:

```
private RiakResult<IList<string>> IndexGetRange(string bucket, string indexName, string minValue, string maxValue, RiakIndexGetOptions options = null)
{
    var message = new RpbIndexReq
    {
        bucket = bucket.ToRiakString(),
        index = indexName.ToRiakString(),
        qtype = RpbIndexReq.IndexQueryType.range,
        range_min = minValue.ToRiakString(),
        range_max = maxValue.ToRiakString()
    };

    options = options ?? new RiakIndexGetOptions();
    options.Populate(message);

    /* at this point, message.max_results is 0 */
    var result = UseConnection(conn => conn.PbcWriteRead<RpbIndexReq, RpbIndexResp>(message));

    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        return RiakResult<IList<string>>.Success(result.Value.keys.Select(k => k.FromRiakString()).ToList());
    }

    return RiakResult<IList<string>>.Error(result.ResultCode, result.ErrorMessage, result.NodeOffline);
}
```

The `RpbIndexReq` object contains the following:

```
private uint? _max_results;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(9, IsRequired = false, Name=@"max_results", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
public uint max_results
{
  get { return _max_results?? default(uint); }
  set { _max_results = value; }
}
[global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
[global::System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
public bool max_resultsSpecified
{
  get { return _max_results != null; }
  set { if (value == (_max_results== null)) _max_results = value ? max_results : (uint?)null; }
}
private bool ShouldSerializemax_results() { return max_resultsSpecified; }
private void Resetmax_results() { max_resultsSpecified = false; }
```

Since `max_results` is a `uint` and not `uint?`, it's always going to be set to 0, despite the protobuf definition specifying it as optional.

Is this the expected result?
Is there a different way that I should go about generating the RpbIndexReq message to ensure that null values are sent across the wire where appropriate?

Comment: Where is `max_results` set to zero? there is a difference between *never had a value* and *was explicitly set a value*

Comment: `_max_results`, the internal field, remains set to `null`, but the property `max_results` is returning 0 as soon as RpbIndexReq is initialized.

Comment: OK - now, what makes you think that it is being transmitted? So far, it sounds like it is behaving exactly like it should - my expectation here would be that field 9 is not sent. So: can you clarify what makes you think that something is misbehaving / being ignored? It isn't obvious in the question, and I want to make sure I'm addressing the right thing

Comment: In this case, 0 results are returned despite there being 5 matching records in Riak. In other cases, when we add the optional timeout parameter (which Riak strictly obeys) queries are immediately returned with no results, regardless of data volume or query complexity. When I repeat the same queries using cURL over an HTTP interface, I get valid data back from Riak.

Comment: k, I'll verify the output this weekend. Note that I can only speak for protobuf-net - if riak does something peculiar with the same objects, I can't advise on that

Comment: Further update: max_results is field 7, but when I drop all the way down to the socket send, the message shows that it's setting 8. I've dumped the output here: https://gist.github.com/peschkaj/5891168 (not like it's terribly legible). If this is a clear indicator that I've gone and broken something, I'll actually be overjoyed.

Comment: no, it is field 9; field 7 is return_terms

Comment: Derp, yeah. Either way, 7 != 8.

Comment: yes, but you can ignore the 8. Actually, the first thing to know is: is that ASCII "8"? Or byte 8? If it is ASCII "8" then it is decimal (from memory, please check) 56. Showing the dump in hex or base-64 would be a lot easier for me :) even if it was byte 8, that doesn't mean "field 8" - protobuf fields have a 3 bit type marker.

Comment: You got it! The first 100 bytes are here https://gist.github.com/peschkaj/5891247 Apologies for the formatting, I've got no idea how to get anything prettier out of VS

Comment: I am mortified to say that I found the error and it's in how we parse the message coming back. @MarcGravell I am sorry if I wasted any of your time on this. Should we ever meet in person (hold me to this), I owe you a meal or at least a very pricey glass of scotch.

Comment: so you're all sorted then? Actually I hadn't spent any time on it yet - was planning to try to repro this evening, so if this isn't a problem any more, that saves me a job... Happy coding.

Comment: I've just checked your profile page: what can I say - Brent has helped us (stack exchange) more times than I can say over the last few years - I don't think a couple of brief comments by me here will dig into that in any appreciable way...